# Why the mismatch between the Haggada's Dayenu and its summary?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada

In the Haggada in the part of [Dayenu](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_Dayenu?lang=bi) it ends off with

> אִלּוּ הִכְנִיסָנוּ לְאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל וְלֹא בָנָה לָנוּ אֶת־בֵּית הַבְּחִירָה
> דַּיֵּנוּ.

> If He had brought us into the land of Israel and had not built us the 'Chosen House' [the Temple; it would have been] enough for us.

and in the summary it ends off with

> וּבָנָה לָנוּ אֶת־בֵּית הַבְּחִירָה **לְכַפֵּר עַל־כָּל־עֲוֹנוֹתֵינוּ**.

> and built us the 'Chosen House' [the Temple] **to atone upon all of our sins**.

Why does it add in the part with the Karbonos in the summary and it doesnt mention it in the main part?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mention *korbanos*: it mentions atonement.

I don't know why there's that difference, but I *guess* the reason is as follows. Atonement is omitted from the poem/song so as to keep the meter and structure. It's added to the followup so as to end on an especially positive note.